# call a function with EventListener

Tags: javascript, api

I really really hope somebody can help me through this here. I have been working on this all weekend to make the code work, and I promises my boss that it would work until monday morning.

**UPDATE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5b1.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: my_API_key
    authorize: true
    onLoad: shareContent
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <script type="in/Login"></script>

    <script>
            // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
            function onLinkedInLoad() {
                IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", shareContent);
            }

            // Handle the successful return from the API call
            function onSuccess(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }

            // Handle an error response from the API call
            function onError(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

            // Use the API call wrapper to share content on LinkedIn
            function shareContent() {

                // Build the JSON payload containing the content to be shared
                var payload = {
                    "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG",
                    "visibility": {
                        "code": "anyone"
                    }
                }

                IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
                .method("POST")
                .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
                .result(onSuccess)
                .error(onError);
            }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run this code I get the Sign in with linkedin button. When I click here I login to LinkedIn. When I am logged in I get a blank page, and in my console I get no erros, only:

But how can I get the share function to pop up?

Comment: where is IN coming from ? is it an argument for the function?

Comment: Hello Kunkka. I am actually not 100% secure on that one. It is in the api: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Comment: are you missing the in/login part specified in the docs? ```<script type="in/Login"></script>```

Comment: yes I actually also did .-/ I just dont understand. It says when you add '<script type="in/Login"></script>' , a button should be generated: I do not get any buttoN?

Comment: ah it is loading now. I am gonna try to build on this again, and then i will get back here

Answer (score -1):

Add this script above

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: My_API_Key_without_quotes
    onLoad:  Linkedin.init
</script>
```

and move here your api initialization

EDIT (this still have error, but now at share request):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addListeners() {
        if(window.addEventListener) {
            document.getElementById('mybtn').addEventListener("click", shareContent, false);
        } else if(window.attachEvent) {
            document.getElementById('mybtn').attachEvent("onclick", shareContent);
        }
    }
    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", shareContent);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to share content on LinkedIn
    function shareContent() {

      // Build the JSON payload containing the content to be shared
      var payload = {
        "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG",
        "visibility": {
          "code": "anyone"
        }
      };

      IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
        .method("POST")
        .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
        .result(onSuccess)
        .error(onError);
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addListeners);

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: My_API_Key_without_quotes
    authorize: true
    onLoad:  onLinkedInLoad
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <button id="mybtn">Try Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I am a bit confused, so sorry for that. I just updated my question, but I dont think that was what you meant?

Comment: I've edited your my answer to make it work. But I'm still facing error 400 Bad request, when we requested share:  IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")

Comment: Thanks again, a lot. I agree with you that I also got that error all the time. I just updated my question. Now the Linkedin button is called, when you click you get the pop up box from LinkedIn where you can log in. The link is actually shared now on LinkedIn. So it is working.. But I can see on https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin under "Share with specific values", that you can customize what you would like to share. Can I also implement that? I get the error 400 Bad request IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json") when I call shareContent()